# Binary XML file line #14: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, layout

I am working with a calendarview and drawerlayout and i get out this error.

My layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/EstiloBase"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_dashboard"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="276dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I dont know what is the error, i try to change all layout_witdth atributtes to other values but the error does not disapear.

My toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

EDIT: Finally i could not find the error. So i had to go back to other version of my app and it is fine, but both versions have same code. I dont understand.

Comment: at first `clean-Rebuild`

Comment: i did that and the error does not disapear

Comment: post your layout  `toolbar` as well

Comment: i edit in the main post. but i use the layout toolbar in other layouts and works fine

Comment: Add width and layout_width and layout_height attribute to your include tag.f you want to override layout attributes using the <include> tag, you must override both android:layout_height and android:layout_width in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

Comment: i did that and clear -> rebuild and the error does not disapear :S

Answer (score 0):

As you are overriding **id** attribute you must specify the height and width.

See the official link for **[include tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Includehttp://)**

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the 
>   tag, you must override both android:layout_height and
>   android:layout_width in order for other layout attributes to take
>   effect.

So your tag become like

```
<include android:id="@+id/tool_bar_dashboard"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Comment: i did that:     <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_dashboard"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> but does not work for me :S the error persist in the line 14

Comment: might you need to clear cache of studio.. `File-> Invalidate cache restart -> Inavalidate and restart` then try again

Comment: i did i does not work for me. i did the next: first i delete the linear layout that contains the calendarview and all its correct, then i delete the drawerlayout and include the linearlayout of calendarview and the error come back. so the error is in the linearlayout of calendarview but i dont know what is it.

Comment: where is this `calendarview`

Comment: i am using caldroid so i create my CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter.java, my CaldroidSampleCustomFragment.java and my custom_cell.xml as the API says

Comment: the log say me this:    at com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment.onCreateView(CaldroidFragment.java:1257) but this is not my class. At this line on the API class,         View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_view, container, false);

Answer (score -1):

Just add wrap_content instead of match_parent in your style

```
 <style name="EstiloBase">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>

</style>
```

Comment: OP set the styles, so it's taking height and width from style

Comment: i apply those attributes by style

Comment: replace android:layout_width="match_parent" with android:layout_width="wrap_content" in your style it will work for me :)